# How can I test Lunascript

Tags: javascript

I heard of it but never saw a link to download it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LunaScript is vaporware.  Last real mention of it was 9 months ago...No download links at the time, and not a peep since.  Don't hold your breath waiting for a release.

Comment: ah ok I better understand or maybe they have found a secret weapon they want to keep for themselves :)

Comment: More likely they had this really ambitious idea, whipped up enough of a prototype to be able to print "hello world", and then ran smack into the reason no one else did what they were trying to do: *Computers aren't smart enough to think like humans.*  Their new language didn't map worth a damn to human thought processes, and that matters bigtime these days.  What little i'm finding suggests they backpedaled from designing a whole new language to building a new framework for an existing language (JS, it's looking like).

Answer (score 4):

There you go..

http://asana.com/luna

it is under development

> **Lunascript sounds great. Can I use it in my project?**
>
> For now we are focused on building the
>   Asana collaboration service, the
>   motivation behind Lunascript, ***but we
>   hope to release Lunascript more widely
>   once it's more mature and we feel
>   comfortable committing to backward
>   compatibility***.